# Remember git passphrase in WSL

Tags: git, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ssh-agent

I run Windows 10 with WSL.  I have the desired behaviour on one computer, but cannot replicate elsewhere.  Here's what I'm after:

1. First time I run a remote git command using my ssh key, git prompts me for the passphrase
2. Subsequent times no prompt, including in new terminal windows (I use ConEmu)
3. When all console windows are closed, back to #1

Things I've tried:

- using `eval $(ssh-agent)`, followed by `ssh-add`; it will remember the passphrase, but if I put it in my `~/.bash_profile` then it prompts me for every new console window, and I open a lot - many of which I'm not using git in.
- setting `git config --global credential.helper` to `cache` or `store`
- everything [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45925964/how-to-use-git-credential-store-on-wsl-ubuntu-on-windows)
- using `bash.exe` and `wsl.exe` to get `git-credentials-manager.exe` to work

Here's an example of what I've put in my `~/.gitconfig`:

`[credential]
   helper = "/mnt/c/Program\\ Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core/git-credential-manager.exe"`

I've installed the `git credential manager` from [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows) and have also tried the main Git For Windows installation as an alternative.

How can I encourage it to remember my passphrase?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I tried the option to add `AddKeysToAgent yes` to `~/.ssh/config` but it doesn't keep it between new tabs on the terminal.

The best solution I found so far is to do the following:

```
sudo apt install keychain
```

Find your hostname using the terminal:

```
hostname
```

Then add the following to your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc` file:

```
/usr/bin/keychain --nogui ~/.ssh/id_rsa
source $HOME/.keychain/YOUR-HOSTNAME-HERE-sh
```

Now, each time you reboot, you’ll have to enter your passphrase. But you only have to do it one time until you reboot or terminate WSL.

If you want to use the same key you already have on Windows you can follow this post [Sharing SSH keys between Windows and WSL 2](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/sharing-ssh-keys-between-windows-and-wsl-2/)

Comment: This worked for me, thank you :) One thing I would recommend is using the `--quiet` flag to suppress the logs outputted each time a new terminal is opened.

Comment: Switching accepted answer to this, as I've tried it and it works even better - now I get asked for my passphrase once within a windows session, and it lasts across all WSL sessions.  Neat!

Comment: @Conan, your answer allows deferring the passphrase entry until the first use of a key. Is it possible to achieve the same behavior with `keychain`?

Comment: Not to my knowledge, I think you'd have to mess around with ssh-agent to get that behaviour.  Note that keychain only asks once, and it remembers until you restart WSL, so it's very unobtrusive

Answer (score 22):

I found the answer!

First, make sure you have `ssh-agent` running all the time by adding `eval $(ssh-agent)` to your `.bash_profile`.

Then add `AddKeysToAgent yes` to your ssh config:

```
touch ~/.ssh/config
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/config
echo "AddKeysToAgent yes" >> ~/.ssh/config
```

You'll get prompted when you first do some ssh, but the passphrase will be automatically added to the `ssh-agent` so you won't have to type it again until you end your session and start a new one.

Comment: It must not be the same on Mac. I followed your instructions, and when I closed and re-opened Terminal, I got `Bad configuration option: addkeystoagent`

Comment: @Ryan Maybe this is related (sorry I don't have a mac): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43382771/addkeystoagent-yes-ssh-config-not-working-on-mac

Comment: Thanks for sending.

Comment: Somehow didn't work for me. I ended up with adding following lines at the end of `bash_profile.sh` file: `echo "Starting the ssh-agent..." eval $(ssh-agent) cd "C:\MyGitRepos" ssh-add` (Note: each command is on new line). This way each time you open the git bash it prompts for the passphrase automatically and you enter it once per session.

Comment: On WSL2 I added `eval $(ssh-agent)` to my `.profile` instead of `.bash_profile` and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 22):

I tried both methods in previous answers (as well as others found elsewhere) on WSL 2 and they either did not work or had caveats I couldn't live with. This is what worked for me.

Install [keychain](https://funtoo.org/Keychain):

```
sudo apt install keychain
```

Then add the following line to your shell's configuration file (likely `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc`):

```
eval `keychain --quiet --eval --agents ssh path_to_your_ssh_key`
```

Now you will only have to enter your password when booting WSL!

Thank you Birk Holland for [this article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/sharing-ssh-keys-between-windows-and-wsl-2/).

Comment: Oh thanks for adding this, keychain never used to work as there was a missing dependency that want available in WSL. Good to know it’s been added, this makes things much easier!

Comment: I have tried every other suggestions, but yours worked at first. Thank you.

Comment: nice. except dont blindly copy ssh keys around. make new ones for every new combination of source and target. You'll thank me later when one or the other gets comprimised or you want to deprecate the key.